# How to access internet website with RobotFramework template?

Tags: robotframework, gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

I'm trying to use [RobotFramework template](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/robotframework) to test an internet website but getting the following error:

```
$ robot_cli $ROBOT_OPTIONS --variable BROWSER:${ROBOT_BROWSER} --outputdir "rf_reports/" --xunit robot-junit.xml $ROBOT_TESTS_DIR
[INFO] Upstream environment_url.txt file found: use base url https://toscatoolbox.orange.com/
==============================================================================
Statistics                                                                    
==============================================================================
Statistics.Get StatsPortailTOSCAToolbox                                       
==============================================================================
Get_Stats_TOSCAToolboxPortal                                          [ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4eb7677b20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Operation timed out')': /wd/hub/session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4eb7677c40>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Operation timed out')': /wd/hub/session
[ WARN ] Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4eb7677d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Operation timed out')': /wd/hub/session
| FAIL |
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.170.227.195', port=5555): Max retries exceeded with url: /wd/hub/session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f4eb7677ee0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Operation timed out'))
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Statistics.Get StatsPortailTOSCAToolbox                               | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Statistics                                                            | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `BASE_URL` variable in your RobotFramework scripts to retrieve the auto-evaluated base URL ?

Have a look at [this example](https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/samples/maven-on-kubernetes/-/blob/master/robot/acceptance.robot#L7).

Because RobotFramework here seems to be trying opening a connection on `10.170.227.195:5555`, which does not seem to correspond with `https://toscatoolbox.orange.com/`